# high level webclient .net

Tags: c#

I am searching for a free .net library that can download webpages and maintain the state of the webapplication.
In fact: a browser without user interface.
I needs to support SSL

Comment: I am going to use HtmlWeb from HtmlAgilityPack, with a custom wrapper: http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard WebClient (or WebBrowser control) can download pages and suchlike OOTB, but what do you mean by "maintain the state"?

Comment: by maintaining the state I mean that the library tracks the cookies and correct header values. I know about the webbrowser control but that relies on Internet Explorer and is not that fast. 
I am looking for a sort of wrapper around Webclient